# Can't create a custom link in phoenix: protocol Enumerable not implemented

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to Elixir/Phoenix, and I want to create a link that does not use the model ID but end up with the error:

`protocol Enumerable not implemented for %XX.YY.Article{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "articles">, content: nil, id: nil, inserted_at: nil, short_title: "lalalilala", slug: 457, title: nil, updated_at: nil}.`

Here is how I try to create the link:

```
  def link_to_article(conn, article_map) do
    article = struct(%XX.YY.Article{}, article_map)

    link article_map.short_title,
      to: page_path(conn, :index, article),
      class: "btn btn-default"
  end
```

I have this implementation for to_param:

```
  defimpl Phoenix.Param, for: XX.YY.Article do
    alias XX.YY.Slug

    def to_param(%{slug: slug, title: title}) do
      "#{Slug.pad_slug(slug)}-#{Slug.slugify_title(title)}"
    end
  end
```

If I give the `article_map` to the link, then the link works but is ugly (the map becomes the query string). What am I missing for `article` to force using `to_param` and create a beautiful URL?

Edit, here is the router declaration:

```
get "/", PageController, :index
get "/:article", PageController, :index
```

As I want the URL to be like `qweqwe.com/padded_slug-article_title`

In the controller I defined the index as:

```
  def index(conn, %{"article" => article_identifier}) do
    [slug|_] = article_identifier |> String.split("-")

    article = XX.YY.get_current_article(slug)

    case article do
      nil -> Phoenix.Controller.redirect(conn, to: "/")
      article -> 
        render conn, "index.html",
          articles: XX.YY.get_articles_for_menu!(),
          current_article: article
    end
  end

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render conn, "index.html",
      articles: XX.YY.get_articles_for_menu!(),
      current_article: XX.YY.get_default_article!()
  end
```

Is this code ugly?

All routes so far:

```
   page_path  GET     /                   QQ.PageController :index
   user_path  GET     /users              QQ.UserController :index
   user_path  GET     /users/:id/edit     QQ.UserController :edit
   user_path  GET     /users/new          QQ.UserController :new
   user_path  GET     /users/:id          QQ.UserController :show
   user_path  POST    /users              QQ.UserController :create
   user_path  PATCH   /users/:id          QQ.UserController :update
              PUT     /users/:id          QQ.UserController :update
   user_path  DELETE  /users/:id          QQ.UserController :delete
article_path  GET     /articles           QQ.ArticleController :index
article_path  GET     /articles/:id/edit  QQ.ArticleController :edit
article_path  GET     /articles/new       QQ.ArticleController :new
article_path  GET     /articles/:id       QQ.ArticleController :show
article_path  POST    /articles           QQ.ArticleController :create
article_path  PATCH   /articles/:id       QQ.ArticleController :update
              PUT     /articles/:id       QQ.ArticleController :update
article_path  DELETE  /articles/:id       QQ.ArticleController :delete
   page_path  GET     /:article           QQ.PageController :index
```

Call stack:

```
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1: Enumerable.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:116: Enumerable.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1823: Enum.reduce/3
    (XX) lib/QQ/router.ex:1: QQ.Router.Helpers.segments/3
    (XX) lib/QQ/router.ex:1: QQ.Router.Helpers.page_path/3
    (XX) lib/QQ/views/layout_view.ex:8: QQ.LayoutView.link_to_article/2
```

Comment: Usually `index` paths do not require object id or any object related data and thus the last argument is just a map or a keyword list of URL params, but it's my wild guess, test it with `show` or `edit` paths.

Comment: Can you post your `router.ex`?

Comment: @Dogbert please see my edit!

Comment: @JustMichael it's because I do not want the URL to have `show` in it. I kept the generated resources for admin purposes and use custom route for viewing.

Comment: @Shautieh do you have another route in your `router.ex` pointing to `PageController.index`? Can you post the output of `mix phoenix.routes`?

Comment: @Dogbert yes there is the default one. I added it, and indeed the code seem to go through that one. This said it is very similar.. Since the time I have been playing with that it seems I broke the default route for the article resources btw.. /articles => same `protocol enumerable` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two routes pointing to the same controller/function (`PageController.index`). The router helper functions are only generated for the first instance of the controller/function which is why you get an error if you try to pass an Article as the third argument.

If you're not using the `get "/", PageController, :index` route, removing that will fix the error.

If you are using it, you'll have to add a custom name to the second route like this:

```
get "/:article", PageController, :index, as: :article_index
```

Now you can use `article_index_path` to generate the paths:

```
article_index_path(conn, :index, article)
```

Comment: Oh ok, I thought I could pattern match on those routes and it used to work before I started fiddling with to_param and everything. I'll do that later and if it works will accept your answer! Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem (I removed the `:article` route and kept the `/`). I have the exact same error when I go to `/articles` too (not `/users`), so I think the problem comes from creating links with `Articles` as param, and thus from the `to_param` function..?? I'll add the call stack in the question

Comment: Did you completely remove that route or change its name using `as:` as I wrote in the answer? According to the stacktrace you're still using `page_path` to generate the article route. You'll have to use the new name as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I completely removed the `/:article` one so the only path `page_path` is `page_path  GET     /                   QQ.PageController :index`. As I said I have the exact same error when I go on the articles page `Request: GET /articles` because `@articles` in the view is filled with `Articles` and it breaks when building the links.

Comment: You'll have to add the other route and use that to generate the link like I wrote in the answer. You cannot pass an article to a `GET /` route.